# Java PopupMenu Checkbox System Tray

Tags: java, swing, popupmenu, jpopupmenu

I'm making an application where I want a checkbox in my java popupmenu(shown below) for the option run at start-up.

Heres the popupmenu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLZQE.jpg

How do i made the Run at start-up option a check box.

Comment: *"Please help"*  Please ask a question - after describing what you have tried in order to achieve the desired result.

Comment: You should tell us more, especially what GUI library you're using, and your code.

Comment: @Hov I presumed Swing, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @AndrewThompson He's probably using AWT. Swing support for the `SystemTray` is still a little spotty.

Comment: partially agreed with @Jeffrey, [awful and partial Listeners are accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8460383/714968), but I think that without any issue for accesible Listeners for Icon in the SystemTray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`CheckboxMenuItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CheckboxMenuItem.html) if you're using AWT or [`JCheckBoxMenuItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBoxMenuItem.html) if you're using Swing.