# Task tray notification balloon events?

Tags: java, swing, notifications, listener, system-tray

Is there any java `event` that could be called on the task tray icon notification balloon, 
that is

```
trayIcon.displayMessage(title, message, TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO)
```

like dropbox uses, when I click on the balloon it take me to the folder where it had downloaded the recent file. Is it possible using java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture trayicon.displayMessage() mouse click on the tooltip baloon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459878/how-to-capture-trayicon-displaymessage-mouse-click-on-the-tooltip-baloon)

Comment: @fas this is true, but answer on that post has some logical errors, so that i have to search it myself :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By doing some R&D I got that tray icon `double click event` get called when we click on the notification balloon. This is what I was looking for.

Check this code:

```
public class Main {
  static Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/tray.gif");

  static TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Tester2");

  public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
    if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
      SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

      trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
      trayIcon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          System.out.println("In here");
          trayIcon.displayMessage("Tester!", "Some action performed", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
        }
      });

      try {
        tray.add(trayIcon);
      } catch (AWTException e) {
        System.err.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I modified it for me in this way.

```
private static String location = Roor_Location_Here// contain the root location
```

Then in the double click `event`

```
/*
 * Double click action performed *
 */
trayIcon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            Desktop dst = Desktop.getDesktop();
            dst.open(new File(location));
            /*
             * reset the location to root location again.
             */
            location = Root_Location_Here // again setting root location                    
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("------- error with folder opening double click "
                    + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

And this is the function I use to call for notification balloon to show the message:

```
public static void showNotification(String title, String msg,
            String location) {
    if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        trayIcon.displayMessage(title, msg, TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
        SystemTrayGUI.location = location;// this sets the location that should be opened when balloon is clicked.

    }
}
```

Comment: @Unihedro where is SystemTrayGUI?

Comment: Anyway `trayIcon.displayMessage` solves my purpose to show message notification and fading it.

Answer (score 2):

- you can add [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to the [Message in SystemTray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)
- [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12707482/714968)

Comment: Beware: ActionListener is not working with Java 7 - 9 (at least on Windows 10) - see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146537

Answer (score -1):

```
package misc;  
/*
 * TrayIconDemo.java
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TrayIconDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
        try {
           // UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        }
        /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //adding TrayIcon.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Check the SystemTray support
        if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
            return;
        }
        final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
        final TrayIcon trayIcon =
                new TrayIcon(createImage("images/bulb.gif", "tray icon"));
        final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

        // Create a popup menu components
        MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("About");
        CheckboxMenuItem cb1 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set auto size");
        CheckboxMenuItem cb2 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set tooltip");
        Menu displayMenu = new Menu("Display");
        MenuItem errorItem = new MenuItem("Error");
        MenuItem warningItem = new MenuItem("Warning");
        MenuItem infoItem = new MenuItem("Info");
        MenuItem noneItem = new MenuItem("None");
        MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");

        //Add components to popup menu
        popup.add(aboutItem);
        popup.addSeparator();
        popup.add(cb1);
        popup.add(cb2);
        popup.addSeparator();
        popup.add(displayMenu);
        displayMenu.add(errorItem);
        displayMenu.add(warningItem);
        displayMenu.add(infoItem);
        displayMenu.add(noneItem);
        popup.add(exitItem);

        trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);

        try {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
            return;
        }

        trayIcon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "This dialog box is run from System Tray");
            }
        });

        aboutItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "This dialog box is run from the About menu item");
            }
        });

        cb1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                int cb1Id = e.getStateChange();
                if (cb1Id == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
                } else {
                    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(false);
                }
            }
        });

        cb2.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                int cb2Id = e.getStateChange();
                if (cb2Id == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    trayIcon.setToolTip("Sun TrayIcon");
                } else {
                    trayIcon.setToolTip(null);
                }
            }
        });

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MenuItem item = (MenuItem)e.getSource();
                //TrayIcon.MessageType type = null;
                System.out.println(item.getLabel());
                if ("Error".equals(item.getLabel())) {
                    //type = TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR;
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Sun TrayIcon Demo",
                            "This is an error message", TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR);

                } else if ("Warning".equals(item.getLabel())) {
                    //type = TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING;
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Sun TrayIcon Demo",
                            "This is a warning message", TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);

                } else if ("Info".equals(item.getLabel())) {
                    //type = TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO;
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Sun TrayIcon Demo",
                            "This is an info message", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);

                } else if ("None".equals(item.getLabel())) {
                    //type = TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE;
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Sun TrayIcon Demo",
                            "This is an ordinary message", TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE);
                }
            }
        };

        errorItem.addActionListener(listener);
        warningItem.addActionListener(listener);
        infoItem.addActionListener(listener);
        noneItem.addActionListener(listener);

        exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tray.remove(trayIcon);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    //Obtain the image URL
    protected static Image createImage(String path, String description) {
        URL imageURL = TrayIconDemo.class.getResource(path);

        if (imageURL == null) {
            System.err.println("Resource not found: " + path);
            return null;
        } else {
            return (new ImageIcon(imageURL, description)).getImage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain what this code is doing and perhaps follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to have a shorted code.