# How do you make Java TrayIcon a Component to associate dialogs with?

Tags: java, swing, system-tray

Java since 1.6 allows the creation of `TrayIcon` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html

What I am trying to do is create a simple app, that just shows dialogs, but because I don't have an actual main application, I don't see anything on the task bar when I do

```
jfilechooser.showOpenDialog(null);
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, ...
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ...
```

because I don't actually have a *parent* component.

What I wanted to do was make a tray icon to represent the parent component without too much hassle to bring up the dialogs when I click on it, but TrayIcon does not implement `Component`.

Answer (score 3):

> because I don't actually have a parent component.

there are two ways for [SystemTray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)

- add [`ActionListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12707482/714968)
- add [`JPopupMenu`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460383/714968)